# Generic method override not working in swift

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

There is a protocol Printable and a struct Printer from a 3rd Party.

```
protocol Printable {}

struct Printer {

    static func print<T>(object: T) -> String {
        return "T"
    }

    static func print<T: Printable>(object: T) -> String {
        return "Printable"
    }

}
```

Now i am making a generic

```
struct Generic<T> {

    var args: T

    func display() {
        print(Printer.print(args))
    }

}
```

and two structs

```
struct Obj {}
struct PrintableObj: Printable {}
var obj = Generic(args: Obj())
var printableObj = Generic(args: PrintableObj())
```

When i call the display functions on both of them.

```
obj.display()
```

displays T

```
printableObj.display()
```

displays T but i want it to print **"Printable"**

One solution i can think of is having two different generics

```
struct Generic<T>
struct PrintableGeneric<T: Printable>
```

Is there any other solution without changing the Printable protocol and Printer struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But the answer is a bit weird. The first part makes a decent amount of sense; the second part is just totally weird. Let's walk through it.

```
struct Generic<T> {
    var args: T
    func display() {
        print(Printer.print(args))
    }
}
```

The correct overload to choose for `print` is decided at compile time, not runtime. This is the thing that confuses people the most. They want to treat Swift like JavaScript where everything is dynamic. Swift likes to be static because then it can make sure your types are right and it can do lots of optimizations (and Swift *loves* to do compiler optimizations). So, compile time, what type is `args`? Well, it's `T`. Is `T` known to be `Printable`? No it is not. So it uses the non-`Printable` version.

But when Swift specializes `Generic` using `PrintableObj`, doesn't it know at that point that it's `Printable`? Couldn't the compiler create a different version of `display` at that point? Yes, if we knew at compile time every caller that would ever exist of this function, and that none of them would ever be extended to be `Printable` (which could happen in a completely different module). It's hard to solve this without creating lots of weird corner cases (where internal things behave differently than public things for instance), and without forcing Swift to proactively generate every possible version of `display` that might be required by some future caller. Swift may improve in time, but this is a hard problem I think. (Swift already suffers some performance reductions so that public generics can be specialized without access to the original source code. This would make that problem even more complicated.)

OK, so we get that. `T` isn't `Printable`. But what if we had a type that *was* unambiguously `Printable` that we knew at compile time and lived inside this function? Would it work then?

```
func display() {
    if let p = args as? Printable {
        print(Printer.print(p))
    } else {
        print(Printer.print(args))
    }
}
```

Oh so close... but not quite. This *almost* works. The `if-let` actually does exactly what you want it to do. `p` gets assigned. It's `Printable`. But it still calls the non-Printable function. ?!?!?!?!

This is a place I personally think that Swift is just currently broken and have high hopes it will be fixed. It might even be a bug. The problem is that `Printable` itself does not conform to `Printable`. Yeah, I don't get it either, but there you go. So we need to make something that *does* conform to `Printable` in order to get the right overload. As usual, [type erasers](http://robnapier.net/erasure) to the rescue.

```
struct AnyPrintable: Printable {
    let value: Printable
}

struct Generic<T> {
    var args: T

    func display() {
        if let p = args as? Printable {
            print(Printer.print(AnyPrintable(value: p)))
        } else {
            print(Printer.print(args))
        }
    }
}
```

And this will print the way you wanted. (On the assumption that `Printable` requires some methods, you'd just add those methods to the `AnyPrintable` type eraser.)

Of course the right answer is not to use generic overloads this way in `Printer`. It's just way too confusing and fragile. It looks so nice, but it blows up all the time.

Comment: Thank you so much for this information. It looks complex to fit in what i am trying to do right now. https://github.com/RahulKatariya/Reactofire/blob/develop/ReactofireTests/Models/GenericResponse/_GenericResponse.swift .. I am trying to make GenericResponseString and GenericResponsePerson tests pass.

Comment: Good luck… I did a lot of experimentation in these kinds of super-clever/magical approaches to basic problems. Personally I found that a few lines of simple code, even if you occasionally have to repeat a couple of tedious lines here or there, works far better, particularly when it's time to debug (I just `guard-let` my JSON parsing now; so much easier). It's not as exciting, but it's worked a lot better in my projects. But best of luck for those still exploring the frontier! It's fun, but there's a lot of frustration like this one.

Answer (score 2):

```
static func print<T>(object: T) -> String {
    if object is Printable {
        return "Printable"
    } else {
        return "T"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But that code is from another source and i can't modify it. I can only make changes in Generic.

Answer (score 1):

To my mind, the only option you have - is to use if-else with type casting in "print()" function

```
static func print<T>(object: T) -> String {
    if let _ = object as? Printable {
        return "Printable"
    }
    return "T"
}
```

or non-generic variant

```
static func print(object: Any) -> String {
    if let _ = object as? Printable {
        return "Printable"
    }
    return "T"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But that code is from another source and i can't modify it. I can only make changes in Generic.