# Swift Protocols with Associated Type and Generics calling wrong function

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift-protocols

I have tried to keep my question very simple. I have been struggling whole day to make it work but no luck. I have two protocols. Decodable and Requestable.

```
protocol Decodable { }
struct D: Decodable { }

protocol Requestable {
    associatedtype Model
}

extension Requestable {
    func returnValue() {
        Utils.doSomething(Model)
    }
}
```

And a class Utils

```
class Utils {
    static func doSomething<T>(param: T) {
        print("Default")
    }

    static func doSomething<T: Decodable>(param: T) {
        print("Decodable")
    }

    static func doSomething<T: Decodable>(param: [T]) {
        print("Decodable Array")
    }
}
```

I create a struct R implementing Requestable and give the type alias Model to String

```
struct R: Requestable {
    typealias Model = String
}
```

When i run the R().returnValue() function, It prints `Default`. As Expected.

I create a struct R2 implementing Requestable and give the type alias Model to D which is implementing Decodable

```
struct R2: Requestable {
    typealias Model = D
}
```

When i run the R2().returnValue() function, It prints `Default`. but i was expecting it would print `Decodable` because the Model `D` conforms to `Decodable`.

I create a struct R3 implementing Requestable and give the type alias Model to [D] where the element of array is implementing Decodable

```
struct R3: Requestable {
    typealias Model = [D]
}
```

When i run the R3().returnValue() function, It prints `Default`. but i was expecting it would print `Decodable Array` because the Model `D` conforms to `Decodable`.

Any kind of help appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Using AnyRequestable and checking in runtime will not work in this case because in real code the Generic is the return value and could not be checked dynamically.

In real code functions signatures are like

```
public static func ResponseSerializer<M>() -> ResponseSerializer<M, NSError> {}
public static func ResponseSerializer<M: Decodable>() -> ResponseSerializer<M, NSError> {}
public static func ResponseSerializer<M: Decodable>() -> ResponseSerializer<[M], NSError> {}
```

Answer (score 3):

This *is* the expected result. You forgot to declare the `Decodable` conformance for your `Model` associated type. This should fix it:

```
protocol Requestable {
    associatedtype Model: Decodable
}
```

---

**Edit:** Reading your comments, I now understand your problem. The thing is, what you're asking of requires the runtime, there is no way to **statically** achieve it:

```
class Utils {
    static func doSomething<T>(param: T) {
        if let param = param as? Decodable {
            print("Decodable")
        } else {
            print("Default")
        }
    }
}
```

Think about it; when you are compiling your code, in the scope of `returnValue`, the compiler only knows that `Model` is an associated type and nothing else. Either you explicitly declare the conformance `Decodable`, or the compiler assumes the default case, which is just `<T>`.

Comment: My Bad. I added a normal case also. And the Model could be [Decodable] too.

Comment: Appreciate your help. I got the same reply here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431712/generic-method-override-not-working-in-swift. But there is no way to check in the runtime. I am struggling since so many days in this.

Comment: @RahulKatariya: You, my friend, are in luck. Because I have invented just the technique you need to solve your kind of problem. Meet [OpaqueSwift](https://github.com/vmanot/OpaqueSwift).

Comment: I have been playing a lot with TypeErasures too. I will give it a try. cuz the real code is always much more complex. Thanks a lot.